# Excel formula to count 'x' in a dynamic range per row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Tried a few and can't seem to find right combination.

currently in `N2`:

```
=IF(A2:A50="x",COUNTIF(I2:M50,"=x"),"--")
```

the A2:A50 will cause the spill `N2` to `N50`, but can't get the individual rows to total. `I2:M2` will only count row 2 for all/any rows, `I2:M50` will count all 49 rows.

can use `=COUNTIF(I2:M2,"=x")` and copy to every row, but this sheet will grow large and new rows won't have this formula.

Comment: Why not convert the range into a table and use the regular formula which will be automatically copied down because of `Table Structured References` behavior unless you are deleting any rows in between, still its a one click features. Or else you might need to look into the newer functions using `LAMBDA()` which will iterate over each rows to perform the requisite calculations.

Comment: Also I have couple of questions here. How do you decide the last row, let say for example, if the last cell in column per your data `A50` is blank and in `I50:M50` one of the cells are not blank, but the last row is `A50` how would you consider the last row here, also will there be anyother number or text in column `A` other than `x`? Can you explain. However you can use a formula like so using `MMULT()` --> `=LET(α,A2:A50,
ß,I2:M50,
σ,MMULT((α="x")*(ß="x"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(ß),,,0)),
IF(σ=0,"--",σ))`

Comment: `=LET(α,A2:A50, ß,I2:M50, σ,MMULT((α="x")*(ß="x"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(ß),,,0)), IF(σ=0,"--",σ))` worked great. Thanks!!. now to review how/what/why. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't get what you meant to say in the last sentences after `Thanks!!`?